# Get distinct rows by eliminating NULLs in multiple columns and rows

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a query and I am stuck at one portion of it. The table at this point looks something like this:

```
id|classid|start|end|CurrentScore|lastYearScore|CurrentTotal|lastYearTotal  
1 |32     |1.23 |2.5|NULL        |NULL         |9.0         |NULL  
1 |32     |1.23 |2.5|7           |NULL         |NULL        |NULL  
1 |32     |1.23 |2.5|NULL        |15           |NULL        |NULL  
1 |32     |1.23 |2.5|NULL        |NULL         |NULL        |20  
...
```

The result im looking for is like this:

```
id|classid|start|end|CurrentScore|lastYearScore|CurrentTotal|lastYearTotal  
1 |32     |1.23 |2.5|7           |15           |9.0         |20
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `GROUP BY` with `MAX()` will help to get the expected result.

The query will be:

```
SELECT id, classid, [start], [end],
       MAX(CurrentScore) AS CurrentScore, 
       MAX(lastYearScore) AS lastYearScore,
       MAX(CurrentTotal) AS CurrentTotal,
       MAX(lastYearTotal) AS lastYearTotal  
FROM TableName
GROUP BY id, classid, [start], [end]
```